# Determining if there are repeated elements in a list in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, pattern-matching

I'm trying to test lists for duplicates but when I compile and enter

```
repeated [1,2,3,4]
```

it outputs True. What's wrong?

```
belongs :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool
belongs n [] = False
belongs n (x:xs) | n == x = True
                 | otherwise = belongs n xs

repeated :: [Integer] -> Bool
repeated [] = False
repeated (x:xs) | belongs x xs = True
                | otherwise = belongs (head xs) xs
```

Comment: `belongs (head xs) xs` checks whether the first element of `xs` (assuming it exists) belongs to `xs`. You want `repeated xs` instead.

Comment: What is the smallest list where `repeated` gives you a different answer than you expect? Now that you have identified a smallest list, you can start evaluating subexpressions of your definition in ghci to see which of them behaves differently than you expect. Eventually you will drill down to an expression so small that it will be obvious either 1. why your expectation was wrong or 2. why the code you wrote was wrong. This is the essence of debugging, and you should expect that the majority of your time and effort in writing code will be spent on this process.

Answer (score 3):

"belongs (head xs) xs" checks whether xs's head is within xs, which will always be true.

(Except when xs is empty, in which case your program will crash! "head" is a partial function, crashes with empty lists)

This would fix it (as pointed by [@talex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3656904/talex) too, but I also suggest making it more general, there is no need to specialize it to Integer):

```hs
repeated :: Eq a => [a] -> Bool
repeated [] = False
repeated (x:xs) | belongs x xs = True
                | otherwise = repeated xs
```

Answer (score 2):

You want

```
repeated :: [Integer] -> Bool
repeated [] = False
repeated (x:xs) | belongs x xs = True
                | otherwise = repeated xs
```